# Format password protected USB flash on ubuntu

Tags: usb

My flash disk is password protected. When I plugged it into my Ubuntu machine I didn't see the flash disk appear, but when I plugged it into Windows I can see the drive but can't open the drive. It gives me the option to "format" but when I click on "format" it says "password protected".

Is there a way to format my drive and back to the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any experience with password protected flash drives but most probably password protection is a software feature and not the hardware one. If that is the case then you can run gparted on ubuntu and delete the current partition(s) on your flash, then recreate a partition(s) and format it to your desired file system.

To install gparted use:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

you can then run it System->Administration->gparted

**Update:**

Your disk may be failing, try running

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb
```

if the ouput from this command says **zero bad blocks** then try write mode test to make sure that your disk is fine. Use

```
sudo badblocks -v -w /dev/sdb
```

for write mode test.

Comment: thank you, i tried that but gparted unable to format the partition error massage: "input/output error during write on /dev/sdb                                                         error fsyncing/closing/dev/sdb:input/output error"

Comment: Your disk may be failing, try running "sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb"

Comment: When i run that command it says "checking for bad blocks (read-only test)" after that  i tested again gparted. but same problem.

Comment: did u let it complete? I mean it should give some output

Comment: Yes i let it complete and the output is "pass completed, 0 bad blocks found."

Comment: Is there another option?

Comment: You can try write mode test to make sure that your disk is fine. use "sudo badblocks -vw /dev/sdb" for write mode test.

Comment: Is the code correct b/c it says command not found. i think i don't have a write permission on the flash.

Comment: I tried "sudo badblocks vw /dev/sdb" and the output is "badblocks : no such file or directory while trying to determine device size" I'm sure the device name is "sdb"

Comment: try "sudo badblocks -v -w /dev/sdb"

Comment: non stop number output......

Comment: the output of badblocks is the list of badblocks. So non stop number output means most of the disk is not usable meaning you need a new disk.

Comment: Ok i will, I really appreciate your help. Thanks,